# What is standard practice for return statements that never run?

Tags: java

I have found myself in the following situation a couple times over the last few months.

Say you have some logic with several different outcomes, all of which return values. And there is **no situation that is not handled** in this logic, what is done with the **final return statement**?

Below is a crude example, but I just wanted to find out what would be the best value/object to return up the stack? What is standard practice here?

```
    for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
        if (i ==5) {
            return String.valueOf(i);
        }
        if (i == 6) {
            return String.valueOf(i);
        }
    }

    return "this will never get returned";
```

Comment: This is probably opinion-based. In cases like this I usually prefer to throw an exception.

Comment: Throw a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: If the location (when hit) indicates a bug in the code base (which it does in this case), throw `AssertionError`: `throw new AssertionError();` (see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AssertionError.html)). Thats what this error was made for.

Comment: This is probably more suitable for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throw a new exception describing that there is an unexpected behavior you can't handle.

```
for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
    if (i ==5) {
        return String.valueOf(i);
    }
    if (i == 6) {
        return String.valueOf(i);
    }
}

throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected error occured");
```

Comment: Note that `AssertionError` was made exactly for this purpose.

Comment: You should avoid throwing generic exceptions.

Comment: You can make a developer’s life better by making the exception informative:  `throw new RuntimeException("'i' was never equal to 5 or 6.");`

Answer (score 1):

A defense programming approach would be to return the value only at the end of the method/function.

```
String myFunction() {
    String returnValue = null;    
    for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
        if (i == 5) {
            returnValue = String.valueOf(i);
            break;
        }
        if (i == 6) {
            returnValue = String.valueOf(i);
            break;
        }
    }

    // Validate return value when necessary
    // if (returnValue == null) {
    //    throw new AssertionError("Return value not set!");
    // }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: To me, returning `null` sounds like a bad idea. It indicates a bug and should thus throw, or immediately notify the caller. In the worst case, the caller does not check for `null` and the program might crash hours later at a different location. You could use `Optional` to force the check to the user. But then, an exception might just be more appropriate.

Comment: for sure a null check can be done - and in the case of an invalid result an exception can be thrown. I just don't like to use multiple return statements in a method.

Answer (score 0):

You can return Optional.

```
Optional<String> getIfExists() { 
   ...   
   return Optional.empty(); 
}
```

Comment: A safe possibility. But I think an empty `Optional` should not indicate a bug, only a valid and correct outcome. So I think this is not a good approach, design-wise. I vote to throw `AssertionError`. But that is opinion-based now.